# Stuck on Oracle SQL constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
ST_ID NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
S_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
ST_FULL_NAME CHAR(25),
ST_GENDER CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
ST_AGE NUMBER(2),
ST_EMAIL VARCHAR(20) CHECK(ST_EMAIL LIKE ‘%@%’),
ST_GDATE DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (S_ID) REFERENCES STAFF,
CONSTRAINT STUDENT_CK_ST_GENDER CHECK (ST_GENDER IN ('M','F')),
CONSTRAINT STUDENT_CK_ST_GDATE CHECK (ST_GDATE > 01-JAN-2014));  --<-- constraint
```

I am stuck on the last constraint. Every time I get a message saying "JAN" invalid identifier.

Can anybody please identify the mistake and correct it for me?

Comment: Use the quote in this way: '01-JAN-2014'

Answer (score 4):

```
CONSTRAINT STUDENT_CK_ST_GDATE CHECK (ST_GDATE > TO_DATE('20140101','YYYYMMDD'))
```

Comment: THANKS, YOU HAVE BEEN A GREAT HELP. IV BEEN STUCK IN THIS FOR AGES.